# Resource not found error when running miscrosoft semantic-kernel

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, azure-openai, semantic-kernel

I am getting the following error when trying to run semantic-kernel using azure open ai

```
Error: (<ErrorCodes.ServiceError: 6>, 'OpenAI service failed to complete the chat', InvalidRequestError(message='Resource not found', param=None, code='404', http_status=404, request_id=None))
```

I am using the following code with reference from https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/blob/main/python/README.md

```
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import AzureChatCompletion

kernel = sk.Kernel()

deployment, api_key, endpoint = "<MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME>","<MY_API_KEY>", "<MY_ENDPOINT>"
# print(f'kernel.add_chat_service("dv", AzureChatCompletion(deployment_name=deployment, endpoint=endpoint, api_key=api_key))')
kernel.add_chat_service("dv", AzureChatCompletion(deployment_name=deployment, endpoint=endpoint, api_key=api_key))
# Wrap your prompt in a function
prompt = kernel.create_semantic_function("""
Write a simple hello-world python program.
""")

# Run your prompt
print(prompt())
```

When I tried finding solution, I ran print(f'') statement over kerrnel.add_chat_service
And I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yashroop.rai\Desktop\semantic-kernel\semantic-kernel.py", line 10, in <module>
    prompt = kernel.create_semantic_function("""
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yashroop.rai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\semantic_kernel\kernel.py", line 851, in create_semantic_function
    return self.register_semantic_function(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yashroop.rai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\semantic_kernel\kernel.py", line 129, in register_semantic_function       
    function = self._create_semantic_function(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yashroop.rai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\semantic_kernel\kernel.py", line 692, in _create_semantic_function        
    service = self.get_ai_service(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yashroop.rai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\semantic_kernel\kernel.py", line 429, in get_ai_service
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: TextCompletionClientBase service with service_id 'None' not found
```

Any solutions ?
The endpoint and api_key are correct because I have been using that as a normal POST request through api call which works fine.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: @furas okay got it

Answer (score 1):

> Resource not found error when running Microsoft semantic-kernel

The above error occurs when you pass an incorrect deployment name or api_key or endpoint in your code.

I created Azure open ai service and deployed **`gpt-35-turbo`** model with the name of **`deploymentname1`**.

**Portal:**

[image]

Now using the below code, I can able to run semantic-kernel with Azure open ai using Python.

**Code:**

```
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import AzureChatCompletion
import semantic_kernel as sk

kernel = sk.Kernel()

deployment="deploymentname1"
api_key="your-azure-api-key"
endpoint="https://<resource name>.openai.azure.com/"
kernel.add_chat_service("dv", AzureChatCompletion(deployment_name=deployment, endpoint=endpoint, api_key=api_key))

prompt = kernel.create_semantic_function("""
Write a simple palindrome python program.
""")

# Run your prompt
print(prompt())
```

**Output:**

````
Here's a simple palindrome python program:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")

if word == word[::-1]:
    print("The word is a palindrome!")
else:
    print("The word is not a palindrome.")
```

This program prompts the user to enter a word, and then checks if the word is the same forwards and backwards (i.e. a palindrome) using slicing. If the word is a palindrome, it prints a message saying so. Otherwise, it prints a message saying the word is not a palindrome.
````

[image]

**Reference:**

[Adding AI services to Semantic Kernel | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/ai-orchestration/kernel/adding-services?tabs=python#chat-completion-deployments)

Comment: I have checked the deployment name, api-key, endpoint as well, they are correct

Comment: @YRR please follow my code and try it and check the packages in the updated version..

Comment: @YRR can you share your screenshot code with the error?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pretty sure the API behaves differently for different model deployments. This sample works for 3.5 but in my experience does not work for gpt4